# Optimize query with multiple column sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT 

   daf.id as affiliate_id,

   daf.name as affiliate_name,

   dal.name as allocation_name,

   dal.id as allocation_id,

   dal.allocation,dal.price,

   (select lead_price from paul.affiliates_price where affiliate_id = daf.id and allocation_id = dal.id) as lead_price,

   (select live from paul.affiliates_price where affiliate_id = daf.id and allocation_id = dal.id) as live,

   (select allocation from paul.affiliates_price where affiliate_id = daf.id and allocation_id = dal.id) as allocation

FROM 

     degreeamerica.affiliates daf, degreeamerica.allocations dal;

ORDER BY daf.id;
```

Can any one please help in optimizing this query using multiple column sub query? Please help!!!

I have already tried this:

```
 SELECT 

   daf.id as affiliate_id,

   daf.name as affiliate_name,

   dal.name as allocation_name,

   dal.id as allocation_id,

   dal.allocation,dal.price

FROM 

     degreeamerica.affiliates daf, degreeamerica.allocations dal 

JOIN 

     (select pap.lead_price,pap.live, pap.allocation_id,pap.affiliate_id from paul.affiliates_price pap) pafp  

ON (dal.id=pafp.allocation_id and daf.id=pafp.affiliate_id) 

ORDER BY daf.id;
```

Its causing error. Unknown daf.id
I am using Cartesian product with multiple column sub query.
I have already spend 8 to 9 hours on this. Please help.
Tell me the mistake in my query the second one or optimize the first one for me.
Please help.

Comment: It looks like you could do this with a single join on paul.affiliates_price on affiliate_id = daf.id and allocation_id = dal.id

Comment: Is it supposed to be a Cartesian join isn't there a key you can join on ?

Comment: I have three tables 1) Affiliates_price 2) affiliates 3) allocations. What i want is 1) I need to map each affiliate with all the allocations, in allocation table. 2) And then find the lead_price,live,etc from paul.affiliates_price using the combination of allocation_id and affiliate_id we get from the Cartesian product in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would give you what you want

```
SELECT daf.id as affiliate_id,
   daf.name as affiliate_name,
   dal.name as allocation_name,
   dal.id as allocation_id,
   dal.allocation
   ,dal.price
   ,ap.lead_Price
   ,ap.live 
   ,ap.allocation 
FROM 

     degreeamerica.affiliates daf
     JOIN paul.affiliates_price ap
     ON daf.id = ap.affiliate_id
     JOIN degreeamerica.allocations dal
     ON dal.id = ap.allocation_id

ORDER BY daf.id;
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but the issue is first i need to find the Cartesian product of "degreeamerica.affiliates daf" and "degreeamerica.allocations dal" so that i could map each affiliate with all the allocations, in allocation table.

Comment: And then need the apply the multiple column sub query to get some columns from paul.affiliates_price table.

Comment: What do you mean? The query above gets all the columns you asked for ?  What other columns do you want ?

Comment: Yes dear. Its getting all the columns but not all the records (rows). Thats is why i have to do by using Cartesian product. Any ways thanks for your responses.

Comment: You can change the joins to Outer joins or Left joins depending on how you want it.

Comment: I don't have any relation between the tables "degreeamerica.affiliates daf" and "degreeamerica.allocations dal". Can left join map the each record of tableA with the all records of tableB ? Means, if tableA have10 records and tableB have 25 records so i need 10*25=250 records in result set? Is it possible using leftjoin or outer join?

Comment: Did you do the full outter join  instead of inner?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.  not sure if it's really optimizing anything.

```
SELECT 
   daf.id as affiliate_id,
   daf.name as affiliate_name,
   dal.name as allocation_name,
   dal.id as allocation_id,
   dal.allocation,
   dal.price,
   p.lead_price,
   p.live,
   p.allocation
FROM 
     degreeamerica.affiliates daf, degreeamerica.allocations dal, paul.affiliates_price p
WHERE 
    p.affiliate_id = daf.id and p.allocation_id = dal.id
ORDER BY 
    daf.id
```

You can also `CROSS JOIN` `affiliates` and `allocations` then `LEFT JOIN affiliates_price`

```
SELECT 
    daf.id as affiliate_id,
    daf.name as affiliate_name,
    dal.name as allocation_name,
    dal.id as allocation_id,
    dal.allocation,
    dal.price,
    p.lead_price,
    p.live,
    p.allocation
FROM 
    degreeamerica.affiliates daf
    CROSS JOIN degreeamerica.allocations dal 
    LEFT JOIN paul.affiliates_price p ON p.affiliate_id = daf.id and p.allocation_id = dal.id
ORDER BY 
    daf.id
```

Comment: Its returning the same result set as Holmes IV answered :(